# How JavaScript basic Object inherits parameters?

Tags: javascript, oop, wikitude

This is a snippet from Wikitude (an AR platform) written in JavaScript

```
this.tracker = new AR.ImageTracker(this.targetCollectionResource, {
    onTargetsLoaded: this.worldLoaded
});
```

My question is about the 'onTargetsLoaded' variable,
where did it come from?
i UNDERSTAND that the curleybraces is the same as

```
new Object();
```

But, still, why would a general object have such a specific parameter such as 'onTargetsLoaded'?
this parameter exists only in classes the the AR plugin provides
and since the Object object doesn't inherit anything why would it have this parameter?
i have dedicated thought and effort to make this question readable and helpful to others
pls try not to downvote, and if you do, pls explain yourself in the comments so i can improve

Comment: "i UNDERSTAND that the curleybraces is the same as `new Object();`" - it's not.

Comment: Why did you tag this with Java?

Comment: the passed object is basically used a list of settings for the constructor, instead of having many arguments. since it's easy to iterate, a constructor can use such arguments in any way it sees fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object literal ( `{ ... }` ) just contain keys and values, none of which have *any* semantic meaning whatsoever to the `Object` class.  Any JS object can contain arbitrary keys and values, and it's down to the code that uses those keys to assign a semantic meaning to those keys.

So, in this case, it's just being used as a way to supply values for keys that the `AR.ImageTracker` class *itself already knows about*.